# Unbounded wildcard passed to method

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

```
public class ColTest {
static<T> T wildSub(ArrayList<? extends T> holder, T arg){
        T t=holder.get(0);
        return t;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<?> list=new ArrayList<Long>(Arrays.asList(2L,3L,7L));
        Long lng=1L;
        ColTest.wildSub(list, lng);
    }
}
```

Really interested why this snippet is legal, because the signature of wildSub takes only `ArrayList` of `T` or derived from `T`, and arg of type `T`. But `<?>` means - some specific type, not known, and how it can satisfy the compiler? After all type `<?>` doesn't mean `<? extends Long>` ...

Comment: this is a nice exercise. Funny thing is that it does not compile in Eclipse! I wonder why.

Comment: @MarianP: Oh, good spot! That looks like a bug to me. Only the second Eclipse compiler bug i'm aware of, so an excellent find!

Comment: It does compile in Eclipse if you define `list` as `ArrayList<? extends Object> list=...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to *capture conversion*. Internally, compiler converts the type of an expression `Foo<?>` to `Foo<X>`, where `X` is a specific albeit unknown type.

Comment: That does not explain why a "specific albeit unkown type" can be compatible with Long.  The correct answer is that it is due to _type inference_, in this case the most specific type argument that will make the call type-correct is `Object`.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is free to infer anything that is compatible with the types of the arguments and return type. In your case it can always infer `T` as `Object`. Which turns the signature into

```
static Object wildSub(ArrayList<?> holder, Object arg)
```

Which means it can take any ArrayList as first argument and anything as second. Since you don't do anything with the return value, `Object` will be okay.

Answer (score 2):

If you think about it as the compiler using Object where ? is used, it makes sense why it would compile. That is all there is to it.

If you are doing any operations dependent on ? being a certain class, you will get a cast exception at run time if the wrong class is passed in.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to existing (correct) answers to make it more clear:

```
    ...
        Object result1 = ColTest.wildSub(list, lng); //compiles fine with Sun's javac
//      Long result2 = ColTest.wildSub(list, lng);   //does not compile without explicit casting
        Long result2 = (Long) ColTest.wildSub(list, lng);   //compiles fine 
    ...
```