# Java generics Eclipse compiler bug?

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, compiler-construction, jvm

My question is a follow up of an other guy's question: [Unbounded wildcard passed to method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788348/unbounded-wildcard-passed-to-method/7799571#7799571)

He was interested why the following code compiled:

```
public class ColTest {
    static<T> T wildSub(ArrayList<? extends T> holder, T arg){
        T t=holder.get(0);
        return t;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<?> list=new ArrayList<Long>(Arrays.asList(2L,3L,7L));
        Long lng=1L;
        ColTest.wildSub(list, lng);
    }
}
```

We came to a conclusion that the trick was that compiler inferred the ? as an Object and made the following Long argument pass thanks to the trivial inheritance of Object->Long.

The code does compile using Sun/Oracle javac (I use 1.6.0_26-b03), but does not compile in Eclipse (I use Helios) where it displays the following compilation error:

```
The method wildSub(ArrayList<? extends T>, T) in the type ColTest is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<capture#2-of ?>, Long)
```

**My question is:**

Is this a bug in the Java compiler implementation Eclipse uses or some kind of ambiguity in Java 'generics inference algorithm' specification that is valid and just implemented differently by Eclipse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to be an Eclipse bug.

T should be inferred to as Object, per 15.12.2.7.

15.12.2.8 also has a catch-all clause: "Any remaining type variables that have not yet been inferred are then inferred to have type Object"

with T=Object, per 15.12.2.2, the method is *applicable*.

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.12

Comment: I need to analyze it a little more (what a beast!), but thanks for being the only person to pull the effort with such a nerdy question with not much reputation to be gained. Respect!